# Any way to give feedback on Interactive notification to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

Say i have an app with interactive notfications to be displayed on the Apple Watch. Lets say its a mail app for example, with a "reply with a thumb" button. When the user clicks that, it would be desirable to display some sort of result on the notification, for example "Mail was sent" or "Unable to send, server not found".

I can't find anything in the notification api to do this, which i find unfortunate. Just wanted to check if someone has the same usecase and if i have missed some (other) way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your app respond to the options in the notifications in the `WKExtensionDelegate` method `handleActionWithIdentifier(_:forRemoteNotification:)`. This can perform a network request which can in turn send another push notification, or you can schedule a local notification as a result of the network request. Check out the `UILocalNotification` API

Comment: Right. I was thinking more client-side, as in i click "reply with thumb", my app cannot send, so i want to tell the user that the reply couldn't be sent. Create another local notification is one way that could work, i guess.